# i am in shift + tilde how to disable the cross mark which is in the middle of the camera in this mode

Tags: graphics, blender

How to disable or remove the cross mark in the middle of the camera in Shift + Tilde mode?

I am encountering an issue where a cross mark appears in the center of the camera when using the Shift + Tilde mode. This cross mark is obstructing my view and hampering my work. I have tried searching for a solution, but I haven't been successful so far.

Could someone please provide detailed steps or code snippets to disable or remove this cross mark from the camera view? I am looking for a solution that works on the most common platforms, such as Windows, macOS, or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my understanding of Blender (used it for years, and made a few scripts however only a limited understanding of the code) what you are looking for isn't a Python rendered gizmo but actually called forth in c/c++; The 'drawFlyPixel' function is compiled in Blender's source code.

Blender's Python API (used to write add-ons) can't touch the C/C++ functions from my understanding. Removing this c/c++ gizmo would require modifying Blender's source code and building your own Blender version.

You can find it called for in
Line 232:

```
  /* draws 4 edge brackets that frame the safe area where the
   * mouse can move during fly mode without spinning the view */

  x1 = xoff + 0.45f * fly->width;
  y1 = yoff + 0.45f * fly->height;
  x2 = xoff + 0.55f * fly->width;
  y2 = yoff + 0.55f * fly->height;
```

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/commit/b117b8e81829fa8e807159e2a5899d0896ea09c6/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_fly.c#L232

Kindly,
Dan